# Cannot clear laravel migrations because of invalid database url config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I accidentally added a wrong database url to my Laravel config now every time I try doing anything with artisan I get this error

```
 InvalidArgumentException 

  The database configuration URL is malformed.
```

I already removed that line but now I can't clear the cache for the config and every time I do anything with artisan I get the same error even when I just run `php artisan help` , something like an infinite loop where laravel has to clear the cache to get rid of the bug but I can't clear it because of the bug

Comment: Have you tried php artisan optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache
```

If it didn't work could you share the config file